# Change table headers

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to change some table headers. And some of these headers contain addition HTML code, like line breaks.

This is the typical setup of the table on the page (page source):

```
<table class="awesometable" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 0;">
    <tr>
        <th style="background: red; color: white;">Male<br /> contestant</th>
        <th style="background: red; color: white;">Female<br /> contestant</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where `Male<br />    contestant`, `Female<br />    contestant` (and a series of other slight variation) should be changed to a simple symbol like `♂` and `♀`.

Using `document.body.innerHTML.replace()` replaces the entire DOM with new nodes, which is undesired, and can also change other instances were the text in the table header is also in plain text and were it shouldn't be changed, although this is rare, and only a minor issue.

Using a selective `nodeType == 3` fails on the additional line breaks.

Any ideas are welcome, code examples (here or at, for example, jsfiddle) are always preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Use `innerHTML` on the table head elements only...

Comment: @Felix `innerHTML` has problems with tables in (yup, you guessed it) IE. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03

Comment: @Matt: As far as I understand this, this is only an issue when you want to add or remove rows from the table. Should be fine to replace text of cells (have not tested it though).

Comment: @Felix I haven't tested it either but I'd sooner just use `innerText`.

Comment: Matt - *innerHTML* is fine to use on cell contents, it always has been and always will be. *innerText* is a proprietary IE property that is not supported by all browsers and is very different to *innerHTML*. MS documentation has **always** said don't use *innerHTML* to modify the table itself. But now that it's part of HTML5 you'll be able to use it for that too in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using jQuery just because it's so much friendlier when dealing with the DOM. Note also that it's probably slightly faster -- which may matter if you have a large table -- not to assign something to `innerHTML` until you've done all the operations on the string. That is, store the value of `innerHTML` in a variable, run `replace` functions, then place the result back in `innerHTML`. (Note also that I'm replacing your `<br />` with `<br>`. At least in Chrome, `innerHTML` will convert XHTML closed single tags to valid HTML, which here is `<br>`.)

Here's a more extensible method ([jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxXtE/)):

```
var replacements = [
  ["Male<br>contestant", "♂"],
  ["Female<br>contestant", "♀"]
];

function runReplacement() {
  $(".awesometable th").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var ih = $this.html();
    $.each(replacements, function(i, arr) {
      ih = ih.replace(arr[0], arr[1]);
    });
    $this.html(ih);
  });
}
```

In addition to the above, you can use `.text()` instead of `.html()` by just ignoring the `<br>` part of each cell (e.g. replacing "Malecontestant" instead of "Male<br>contestant"). [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dxXtE/8/).

**EDIT:**

And for correcting an example below:

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("th"); 
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  headers[i].innerHTML = headers[i].innerHTML.replace("Male<br>contestant", "♂")
                           .replace("Female<br>contestant", "♀");
}
```

For silliness like focusing on terseness (70 characters shorter, ignoring excess whitespace):

```
$("th").each(function(){$(this).html($(this).html()
.replace("Male<br>contestant","♂").replace("Female<br>contestant","♀"));});
```

Comment: You realise that jQuery's *html()* method is just innerHTML (as suggested by Alex)? And that Headshota's answer does it in 4 lines of code?

Comment: @RobG On jQuery, I'm recommending it as he's likely working with the DOM. Also, the question content dictates an array over magic strings, hence declaring them up top. Further, jQuery's `html()` assign removes element nodes -- which is an issue here -- and deals with whitespace. Anyway, I assume you realize that `innerHTML.replace` does not assign anything to `innerHTML` (it merely replaces the string, but there's nothing to capture the result). And JavaScript doesn't use a dot for string concat. And `innerHTML` converts XHTML single tags to their HTML counterparts (e.g. `<br /> #=> <br>`).

Comment: Bryan - if you supply a string to jQuery's html() it **will** change the innerHTML of the node by assigning a new value to its innerHTML property - read the code (line 5649 in v 1.6.1). The only thing it does of any consequence it wrap it in try..catch and if it fails, remove all content *then* set the innerHTML property.

Comment: I was wrong about whitespace, but, like I said, it removes element nodes. I think the first graf demonstrates that I know what `.html()` does. In any case, that particular function is definitely not why I'm recommending jQuery. What's more important is what he's doing aside from this, and modifying table headers is a giveaway for a good bit of DOM traversal and manipulation -- click to replace headers, click to sort, etc. -- which justifies considering a library. Looking at most SO questions in pure isolation would never justify a 31 KB prefix, but I'm trying to extrapolate his needs.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
  var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('th'); 
  headers[0].innerHTML = '&#x2642;';
  headers[1].innerHTML = '&#x2640;';
```

Shows the concept. Better to give the respective cells an id or class to identify them rather than using the content. You could also do something like:

```
  var cell, headers = document.getElementsByTagName('th'); 

  for (var i=0, iLen=headers.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    cell = headers[i];

    if (cell.innerHTML.match('Male') ) {
      cell.innerHTML = '&#x2642;';
    }
      else if (cell.innerHTML.match('Female')) {
      cell.innerHTML = '&#x2640;';
    }    
  }
```

Comment: -1? That's funny! It's the simplest and fastest of all the answers and doesn't require a library. +1 from me anyway.

Comment: Bryan I can't help you without details given. what's not working, do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with something like

```
function replace(text)
{
    return text.replace('Male', '♂').replace('Female', '♀');
}

var ths = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('th'),
    i = ths.length,
    th, text;
while (i-- && (th = ths[i], text = th.innerText))
{
    if (text)
    {
        // IE, Safari, Chrome, Opera
        th.innerText = replace(text);
    }
    else
    {
        // Everything but IE <9
        th.textContent = replace(th.textContent);
    }
}
```

As requested, jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4EwGt/

Yes, [`innerText || textContent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04) is a PITA.

---

> I want to replace the entire header, `Male<br /> contestant` and `Female<br /> contestant`, not just the first word, and trying the whole in your example doesn't work. Only seems to remove the line break, doesn't change the text.

Use this replace function instead:

```
function replace(text)
{
    return text.replace('Male\ncontestant', '♂')
        .replace('Female\ncontestant', '♀');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/8W3cM/

Comment: I want to replace the entire header, `Male<br /> contestant` and `Female<br /> contestant`, not just the first word, and trying the whole in your example doesn't work. Only seems to remove the line break, doesn't change the text.

Comment: See my edit. It definitely works in Chrome, though I'm not sure if IE will convert `<br/>` into `\n` in `innerText`.

Comment: Does indeed work in Chrome, doesn't work in Safari, which is weird. Anyway, Bryan's code works in Safari as well. Thanks.